# Do producer credits now require "pga" after their names?

Tags: production, credits

During the end credits of *Star Trek Beyond*, all the producers had their names followed by "p.g.a". This apparently stands for Producer's Guild of America certification.

Are they *required* to append this to the end of names now, when someone is credited specifically as a producer? Required, that is, by the PGA, as part of a contract or other Hollywood rules?

Or was this just something as part of *Beyond*'s production?

Perhaps this has existed already in films, and I just didn't notice. When it started would be helpful, if it's been long before *Beyond*.

Answer (score 3):

[This article on the Wrap](http://www.thewrap.com/the-producers-guilds-long-rocky-road-to-reforming-the-producers-credit-exclusive/) -- from 10 September 2013 -- explains:

> Determined to get proper recognition for producers that actually do
>   the work, the Producers Guild of America has been lobbying for better
>   movie credits for years. It spent years trying to sell the idea to an
>   industry in which movie credits were too often currency to be bought,
>   bartered and corrupted by anybody with the clout to do so.
>
> This summer, the last major studio holdouts agreed to the so-called
>   “Producers Mark,” putting an end to the PGA’s decades-long battle for
>   respect. Sixty-plus movies have since become certified with the
>   Producers Mark; in those films’ credits, **“p.g.a.” follows the names of
>   the producers judged by the guild to have truly earned the credit on a
>   film.**
>
> [...]
>
> Yet it has not been able to reduce the number of producer credits on
>   movies like “Lee Daniels‘ The Butler,” which bears 41 different
>   producer credits, much to the guild’s chagrin. **The Producers Mark only
>   deals with producers claiming the “Produced by” credit**, which is why
>   the 36 associate producers, executive producers and co-producers on
>   “The Butler” went unchallenged.
>
> **If that film is nominated, it will go through the vetting process to
>   determine which of the five individuals given a “Produced by” credit
>   will receive the official “p.g.a.” producer’s mark and become eligible
>   for awards.**